# MediaElement.js: Trigger event, if some specific audio file has ended

Tags: javascript, jquery, mediaelement.js

Referring to [MediaElement.js](http://mediaelementjs.com/). How to trigger an event (call a function), if some specific audio file has ended?

```
var myAudioFiles = ['audioFile1.wav', 'audioFile2.wav', 'audioFile3.wav'];
var myPlayer = new MediaElementPlayer('#myPlayer');

myPlayer.setSrc(myAudioFiles[0]);
myPlayer.play();
```

Pseudo Code:

```
if (hasEnded(myAudioFiles[0])) {
    doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try this.

```
$(function(){
    $('audio,video').mediaelementplayer({
        success: function(player, node) {
            player.addEventListener('ended', function(e){
                player.src = 'media/somefile.mp4';
                player.load();
                player.play();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

copied from here:
   [mediaelement.js - play another video at end of 1st video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269969/mediaelement-js-play-another-video-at-end-of-1st-video)